# Defining a static directory into app.yaml make app crash

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a weird issue on GAE `standard` (running `node`), more precisely with my `app.yaml` below.

```
runtime: nodejs8

# Environment variables
env_variables:
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT: '...'

# Static directories and files
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: public
```

**Without** the `handlers` part, everything works like a charm: my app is deployed and works. Note that the `size` is 4.8 MB (version `1-0-43`).

[image]

However, **with** the `handlers` part, my app doesn't work anymore: `4xx` error and an app `size` of 324 KB (version `1-0-43`).

The sole purpose of the `handlers` part is to define a `directory` to serve static assets (CSS, JS, images...).

Any clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you add your `static_dir` handler definition the entire content of your `public` subdirectory is no longer (by default) uploaded together with your app code (most likely explaining the app size difference). Instead it's uploaded to a different location to be served directly by the GAE infra, see [How to serve static files in AppEngine Standard and nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888860/how-to-serve-static-files-in-appengine-standard-and-nodejs/50889382#50889382)

It sounds that your app may need some of those files as well. In such case the easiest solution would be to add the `application_readable` flag to the static definition, causing that directory to be uploaded both in the static content location and together with your app code, see [GAE: file_get_contents() and static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414346/gae-file-get-contents-and-static-files/41414501#41414501).

To speedup your deployments could also try to separate the static content in 2: one portion not needed by your app code, deployed without `application_readable` (thus not also uploaded with your app code, deployed faster) and one with the flag. If it's not too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing static_dir from 'public' to 'static'. Because the url and static_dir are usually located at the same place. Please try it and let me know. Cheers!

```
    # Static directories and files
      handlers:
      - url: /static
        static_dir: static
```

Comment: I tried and changed my `app.js` accordingly to `app.use('/static', express.static('static'))`. No change, but still works perfectly locally.